# Filter SIP Messages from log file

Tags: regex, perl

I work with VoIP solutions as a day to day job. I often get SIP messages debugs from devices I manage. Most of the times however, those logs contain more calls than I require to analyze, so it would be great if I could filter them out.

I want a tool that can, if I give it a log file and the Call-Id's I need, filter the log file to include only those SIP messages.

Unfortunately, SIP messages are more than one line, so my experience with grep is not sufficient to get it to work.

I started to program something in Perl for this, but any further than checking if I had the proper amount of parameters I didn't get. Is Perl the best language to go about this? I have included a part of the input here:

```
Jan 28 11:39:37.525 CET: //1393628/D5CC0586A87B/SIP/Msg/ccsipDisplayMsg:
Received: 
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.218.16.2:5060;branch=z9hG4bKB22001ED5
From: "Frankeerapparaat Secretariaat" <sip:089653717@10.210.2.49>;tag=E7E0EF64-192F
To: <sip:022046187@10.210.2.49>;tag=25079324~19cc0abf-61d9-407f-a138-96eaffee1467-27521338
Date: Mon, 28 Jan 2013 10:39:32 GMT
Call-ID: D5CCA1AE-686D11E2-A881ED01-8DFA6D70@10.218.16.2
CSeq: 102 INVITE
Allow: INVITE, OPTIONS, INFO, BYE, CANCEL, ACK, PRACK, UPDATE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY
Allow-Events: presence
Supported: replaces
Supported: X-cisco-srtp-fallback
Supported: Geolocation
Session-Expires:  1800;refresher=uas
Require:  timer
P-Preferred-Identity: <sip:022046187@10.210.2.49>
Remote-Party-ID: <sip:022046187@10.210.2.49>;party=called;screen=no;privacy=off
Contact: <sip:022046187@10.210.2.49:5060>
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 209

v=0
o=CiscoSystemsCCM-SIP 2000 1 IN IP4 10.210.2.49
s=SIP Call
c=IN IP4 10.210.2.1
t=0 0
m=audio 16844 RTP/AVP 8 101
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=ptime:20
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-15

Jan 28 11:39:37.529 CET: //1393628/D5CC0586A87B/SIP/Msg/ccsipDisplayMsg:
Sent: 
ACK sip:022046187@10.210.2.49:5060 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.218.16.2:5060;branch=z9hG4bKB2247150A
From: "Frankeerapparaat Secretariaat" <sip:089653717@10.210.2.49>;tag=E7E0EF64-192F
To: <sip:022046187@10.210.2.49>;tag=25079324~19cc0abf-61d9-407f-a138-96eaffee1467-27521338
Date: Mon, 28 Jan 2013 10:39:36 GMT
Call-ID: D5CCA1AE-686D11E2-A881ED01-8DFA6D70@10.218.16.2
Max-Forwards: 70
CSeq: 102 ACK
Authorization: Digest username="Genk_AC_1",realm="infraxnet.be",uri="sip:022046187@10.210.2.49:5060",response="9546733290a96d1470cfe29a7500c488",nonce="5V/Jt8FHd5I8uaoahshiaUud8O6UujJJ",algorithm=MD5
Allow-Events: telephone-event
Content-Length: 0


Jan 28 11:39:37.529 CET: //1393627/D5CC0586A87B/SIP/Msg/ccsipDisplayMsg:
Sent: 
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.8.11:5060;branch=z9hG4bK24ecaaaa6dbd3
From: "Frankeerapparaat Secretariaat" <sip:3717@192.168.8.11>;tag=e206cc93-1791-457a-aaac-1541296cf17c-29093746
To: <sip:022046187@192.168.8.28>;tag=E7E0F8A4-EA3
Date: Mon, 28 Jan 2013 10:39:32 GMT
Call-ID: fedc8f80-10615564-45df0-b08a8c0@192.168.8.11
CSeq: 101 INVITE
Allow: INVITE, OPTIONS, BYE, CANCEL, ACK, PRACK, UPDATE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, REGISTER
Allow-Events: telephone-event
Remote-Party-ID: <sip:022046187@192.168.8.28>;party=called;screen=no;privacy=off
Contact: <sip:022046187@192.168.8.28:5060>
Supported: replaces
Supported: sdp-anat
Server: Cisco-SIPGateway/IOS-15.3.1.T
Session-Expires:  1800;refresher=uas
Require: timer
Supported: timer
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Disposition: session;handling=required
Content-Length: 247

v=0
o=CiscoSystemsSIP-GW-UserAgent 7276 9141 IN IP4 192.168.8.28
s=SIP Call
c=IN IP4 192.168.8.28
t=0 0
m=audio 30134 RTP/AVP 8 101
c=IN IP4 192.168.8.28
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-15
a=ptime:20
```

The program I envision would take 2 or more arguments: the log file and then any amount of Call-ID's of calls I am interested in. It would then filter out only the relevant messages and print it to stdout.

Note that a single SIP message may include a blank line. The next message starts only when a new timestamp is shown.

Comment: where is the call id you are trying to filter by?

Comment: In each SIP Message block there is a 'Call-ID:  .... ' line. That is what I want to filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %callIDs = map { $_ => 1 } splice @ARGV, 1, @ARGV - 1;
my $recordPrinted;

local $/ = '';

while (<>) {
    if ( /Call-ID:\s+(.+)/ and $callIDs{$1} ) {
        $recordPrinted = 1;
        print;
        next;
    }

    print if $recordPrinted and /\brtpmap\b/;

    $recordPrinted = 0;
}
```

Usage: `perl scriptName.pl logFile callID [callID]`

When you send a script parameters, they end up in `@ARGV`.  The `splice` takes (and removes) the elements from 1 on to build a hash's keys.  The zeroth element is the log file name.

`local $/ = '';` sets paragraph mode, i.e., a whole chunk of text separated by blank lines is read at a time.  The regex captures the `Call-ID` and if a key exists for that ID, the line is printed.  Also, a flag is set to indicate that a 'record' has been printed, since there may be another 'chunk' to that record.

If a record's been printed and a field is found that occurs in a second part of the record (rtpmap), that chunk is printed.

Comment: Wow, thanks. That is exactly what I  need. I don't think I would have found all the perl features you used to get this so elegant. I've been looking at it for some 10 minutes now, and I only now start to understand it completely.

Comment: @TomRibbens - You're most welcome!  Am glad it worked for you.

Comment: Apparently it doesn't work with files with CRLF line terminators. I'll investigate.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
if ($subject =~ m/(?im)(Call-ID: (.+))$/) {
    $result = $2;
} else {
    $result = "";
}
```